# How to grouping same key to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question if I have table like this, and I have the same value in field-2, then I want to make the Field-2 to be a key of my array, so if Field-2 is the same value it's mean it will be the same of key in the array:

this is the table:

```
    _____________________________
    | Field-1 | Field-2 | Field-3 |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row1    |    2    |    S    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row2    |    2    |    A    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row3    |    1    |    S    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row4    |    3    |    S    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row5    |    1    |    A    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row6    |    4    |    A    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row7    |    5    |    S    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
    | row8    |    5    |    A    |
    |_________|_________|_________|
```

the result I want to like this:

```
  Array
    (
         [1] => Array
              (
                 [0] => row3
                 [1] => row5
              )
         [2] => Array
              (
                 [0] => row1
                 [1] => row2
              )
         [3] => Array
              (
                 [0] => row4
                 [1] => 
              )
         [4] => Array
              (
                 [0] => 
                 [1] => row6
              )
    [5] => Array
              (
                 [0] => row7
                 [1] => row8
              )
```

Comment: Can you give as example of how your table is accessible? array? (please share the input)

Comment: what is the original array? field-1, field-2 and field-3... what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = array();
foreach($input as $array){
 $output[$array['Field-2']][] = $array['Field-1'];
}
ksort($output); // added as per additional requirement.
```

Comment: how to sorting to asc the key, in this code an array key not  ASC?

Comment: @rizki this caught my eye and I've updated my answer to include this

Comment: @rizki updated my answer, also I recommend that you read into php arrays which is a very fascinating subject and very easy for the beginners to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't provided any code along with your answer I'll draw some up that I think will at least be similar to what you're using - this creates an array, loops through each row of the table and adds an element to a subarray with the key being whatever's in column two. Due to the fact it adds a new element each time, it won't overwrite the previous.

```php
$array = [];
foreach ($table as $row) {
  $array[$row[1]][] = $row[0];
}
ksort($array); // Sorts the array so that the keys are in ascending order
```

Comment: wont this group by the first column? where as the OP wants it to be groupd by the second one?

Comment: Array indexing starts at 0, so index 1 is the second column

Comment: You might want to re check the question :)

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib Updated